# Как сохранить 0 при переводе в 16-ричную систему c#

Tags: c#

Я хочу перевести цвет RGB в HEX. Для этого использую `Convert.ToString()`:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("HEX - #{Convert.ToString(color.R, 16)} {Convert.ToString(color.G, 16)} {Convert.ToString(color.B, 16)}"));
```

Если запихнуть туда цвет rgb(9, 9, 0), то выйдет 990, а нужно 090900.

Как сразу впихнуть нули, но при этом легально? Или это только ifом и конкатенацией сотворять?

Comment: Что такое `color`? Из какой библиотеки класс/структура? Или ваш собственный тип? Нет ли у него свойства наподобие RGB, возвращающего int? Тогда проще использовать его с форматом `X6`.

Comment: сolor - локальная переменная типа Color. Color (System.Drawing.Color) - стандартная структура(как я думал, известная). Такого свойства нет, есть только R, G и B отдельно (и для HSV тоже).  И мне в любом случае нужно по r g b разбить, так что в формат X6 мне смысла преобразовывать нет. Да и из трёх байтов разбивать по одному не умею.

Comment: Да, это известная структура из WinForms. Но, например, в WPF есть своя структура `System.Windows.Media.Color`. В других библиотеках могут другие типы с таким именем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать `int.ToString(format)`, где формат "X2" - hex в два символа.

```
Console.WriteLine($"HEX - #{color.R.ToString("X2")} {color.G.ToString("X2")} {color.B.ToString("X2")}");
```

Можно записать короче:

```
Console.WriteLine($"HEX - #{color.R:X2} {color.G:X2} {color.B:X2}");
```

---

Выяснилось, что имеется в виду структура `System.Drawing.Color`. У неё есть метод `ToArgb()`. С его использованием код получается ещё короче:

```
Console.WriteLine($"HEX - #{color.ToArgb():X6}");
```

Но мы получим вывод `090900` лишь в том случае, если компонент alpha равен 0. Если альфа не ноль, то будет присутствовать в выводе.